# Spotfire button change color when clicked / selected

Tags: javascript, python, html, data-visualization, spotfire

I am trying to make the buttons created in Spotfire to change color or fade when they are clicked. Basically we want the buttons to show they are marked when selected.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're editing the HTML around a button, it looks like you can make it bold or change the size of the text, though you can't change the color (Or, oddly enough, underline or italicize the text in the button).

So copy the html code for the text area into a string, and on your script for the button click, add the following general setup.

Example Initial HTML:

```
<p><SpotfireControl id="724c2b260722473caecaef18a2b3b695" />
</p>
```

Example Code (vTextArea is a parameter of Type Visualization referencing the text area your button is in):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from System import Guid

page = Application.Document.ActivePageReference

fullhtml = '<p><font size="3"><b><SpotfireControl id="724c2b260722473caecaef18a2b3b695" /></b></font></p>'

ta=vTextArea.As[VisualContent]()
ta.HtmlContent=fullhtml
```

I know this doesn't do exactly what you were asking for, but it does succeed in showing the user which button they've clicked.